# HTML Construct To Render Chat History

Tags: html

I am working on a demo Web Sockets application. I have the communication set up between the client and the server and they are able to exchange the information between them. I am interested in representing the chat history in the form of a scrollable, color differentiated UI. I initially went with a TextArea which was perfect. Only thing was I am unable to color code the server and user responses differently. I then fell back to LI elements from Bootstrap. But they are appearing very bloated and one more thing that I noticed is since they are part of an UL, I am not getting the scroll bar. So the user input textbox is getting pushed to the bottom of the page as and when there is more communication between the client and the server.

Request you to suggest me an alternative HTML construct which I can explore.

[image: Current Chat History UI]

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>A WebSocket Example!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lets Chat!</h1>
    <small id="subtextMessage" class="form-text text-muted">Great conversations happen over a socket!.</small>
    <BR><BR>

    <!-- Building the Form -->
    <form class="" id="chatform" onsubmit="clearTextInput();return false">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="conversationHistory">Conversation History</label>
            <ul class="list-group" id="conversationList">
            </ul>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="conversationHistoryTextArea" rows="10" readonly></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="labelMessage">Type your message</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMessageTextBox" aria-describedby="inputMessage">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>
    </form>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/chatscript.js">    
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function clearTextInput()
{
    $("#inputMessageTextBox").val("");
    console.log( "Reached Here" )
}

function sendMessage() {
    ws.send( $("#inputMessageTextBox").val() );   
    $("#conversationHistoryTextArea").val( $("#conversationHistoryTextArea").val() + "\n" + "YOU: " + $("#inputMessageTextBox").val() );

    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText =  $("#inputMessageTextBox").val();
    li.classList.add("list-group-item");
    li.classList.add("list-group-item-info");
    document.getElementById('conversationList').appendChild(li);
}

let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");
ws.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log("Client: WebSocket request accepted.");
};

ws.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log("Received from the server" + event.data);

    if( $("#conversationHistoryTextArea").val().trim().length > 0 )
        $("#conversationHistoryTextArea").val( $("#conversationHistoryTextArea").val() + "\n" + "SERVER: " + event.data );
    else
        $("#conversationHistoryTextArea").val( "SERVER: " + event.data );

    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText =  event.data;
    li.classList.add("list-group-item");
    li.classList.add("list-group-item-primary");
    document.getElementById('conversationList').appendChild(li);
};
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML `<p>` element, and use CSS classes for each different party.

You can also use `<span>` but you will have to deal with the line break.

I am sure there are many other solutions for this.

Comment: Yes, they work similar to the LI example that I gave. But how do I force a scrollbar if the number of rows exceed say 15?. Is that possible?. Please suggest.

Comment: You can use CSS `overflow` to force a scrollbar: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp